# How to turn off just one click function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem, which is that a function works and repeats without stopping. I tried many methods and it did not work
This is the code:

```js
var clickCounter10 = 0;
var movetool10 = document.getElementById('movetool10')
movetool10.onclick = function() {
  clickCounter10++;
  if (clickCounter10 == 2) {
    document.getElementById('movetool10').innerHTML = 'hi user one';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('movetool10').innerHTML = 'hi user two';
  };
};
```

```html
<button class="button" id="movetool10" onclick="movetool10();stoptool10()">click me !</button>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the definitions of the functions `movetool10()` and `stoptool10()`. Note you are not doing yourself any favors by naming the function with the same name as the id of the element, nor setting the `onclick` through both HTML and JavaScript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the event listener, but with your logic:

`if (clickCounter10==2) {` will only be `true` once since you keep incrementing the counter. It should be either `if (clickCounter10 % 2 === 0) {` or you should be resetting it to 0 value when it reaches 2.

```js
var clickCounter10 = 0;
var movetool10 = document.getElementById('movetool10')
movetool10.onclick = function() {
  clickCounter10++;
  if (clickCounter10 % 2 === 0) {
    document.getElementById('movetool10').innerHTML = 'hi user one';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('movetool10').innerHTML = 'hi user two';
  };
};
```

```html
<button class="button" id="movetool10" onclick="movetool10();stoptool10()">click me !</button>
```

```js
var clickCounter10 = 0;
var movetool10 = document.getElementById('movetool10')
movetool10.onclick = function() {
  clickCounter10++;
  if (clickCounter10 === 2) {
    clickCounter10 = 0; // condition met, resset so it'll be met again
    document.getElementById('movetool10').innerHTML = 'hi user one';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('movetool10').innerHTML = 'hi user two';
  };
};
```

```html
<button class="button" id="movetool10" onclick="movetool10();stoptool10()">click me !</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickCounter10 = 0;
var movetool10 = document.getElementById('movetool10')
var TempNumber = 1;
movetool10.onclick = function() {
    var buttonName = TempNumber ==1?"hi user one":"hi user two";
    TempNumber = TempNumber ==1?2:1;
    document.getElementById('movetool10').innerHTML =buttonName;
};
```